# how to verify facebook profile pic last update time?

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-fql

I have a simple android app which interacts with Facebook through FQL queries.

When the app loads for the first time I run an FQL query for retrieving the user's friends data and profile picture and I save the it locally on the device.

When the app loads for the second time, I'm retrieving the data from the phone.

My question is how can I know for every friend of the user what is the profile picture last modification time?

I want to re-fetch the profile picture only if needed.

Thanks in advance,
Oz Radiano.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could also store the profile picture id (or hash it, better) and compare it with the previously stored one. In case they are different, you should download the new picture.

Comment: I already found out that a part of the image of a user can be taken to query the photo table for modified date time like this:

SELECT pid, modified FROM photo WHERE pid="0000_0000" 

but it means that I need to query thousands of queries (in case that the user have a lot of friends) and i'm looking for easier way...

Comment: What kind of application are you doing? Maybe you can select just a couple of users for this operation.

Comment: In the program I need all the user's friends and maybe even its friends of friends

Comment: I would suggest that you warn your users your application demands a lot of bandwidth:)